# keyboard down key not working if chosen dropdown height set

Tags: jquery-chosen

I have set max height for chosen dropdown using following code

```
 `.chosen-container .chosen-results {     height:100px !important; }`
```

but that results in keybord down arrow key not working properly 
on press of down key scroll bar not reaches to end

Comment: Adding that css rule to an otherwise working chosen dropdown works fine for me.  Can you share a bit more of your html/code?

Answer (score 0):

please try setting `max-height:100px` instead of height.